# Get Authorization fail in creating certificate of let's encrypt

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

[image]

I would like to create certificate of let's encrypt.
but I keep getting this error as image.
Can someone help me to give any idea for this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned in a provided screenshot, the temporary token file, which Let's Encrypt is using to verify the domain name ownership, should be reachable from the net.
In this case, the request from Let's Encrypt servers to this temporary file fails because A record the domain cannot be found.
In other words, it is not possible to get Let's Encrypt certificate while DNS is not properly configured.
Here is the more detailed explanation of the authorization procedure - https://letsencrypt.org/how-it-works/